# Cmd+click method points to different ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitextfielddelegate

I have 2 ViewControllers. In both i have implemented `-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method. But when i CMD + ClICK the method in 2nd ViewController, it looks like it is referring to the 1st viewController instead of the delegate. Refer the image.

What is going wrong?

http://i62.tinypic.com/fon051.png

Code Below

```
 -(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
NSLog(@"in text edit %@ ",textField.text);
// UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[[textField superview]superview] superview];

CGPoint buttonPosition = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:table2];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table2 indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[table2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIStepper *st = (UIStepper *)[(UITableViewCell *) textField.superview viewWithTag:123];
NSString *txt=[[NSString alloc]init];
txt=textField.text;
NSLog(@"val is: %@",txt);

[st setValue:textField.text.doubleValue];

//// NSIndexPath *indexPath=[table2 indexPathForCell:cell];
[self updateStepper:st fromTetabxtField:textField];


NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex;



if(selectedSegment == 2){
    [pobQuantity replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:txt.intValue]];

    textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[pobQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue]];

    NSLog(@"pob  at Index %d is %@",indexPath.row,[pobQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}

if(selectedSegment == 3){
    [brandRemindersQuantity replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:txt.intValue]];

    textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[brandRemindersQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue]];
    NSLog(@"brand  at Index %d is %@",indexPath.row,[brandRemindersQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}


}
```

Setting UItextField Delegate in CellforRowAtIndexPath method.

```
        UITextField *lbl1 = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(400, 16, 35 ,15);
        [lbl1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        lbl1.text = @"1";
        lbl1.delegate=self;
        [lbl1 setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
        [lbl1 setTag:456];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];
```

Comment: i guess in one controller you did cmd+Click so it is is referring to the remaining one.

Comment: yea.... but the question is... why?

Comment: this features picks where ever this signature is available and on clicking it jumps to the respective class. So there is no need to jump on the same class since you already located there.

Comment: actually i was not talking about the feature. What is happening is, after this delegate gets executed, viewDidLoad method of the other class is getting executed. Which shouldn't happen.

Comment: Then check value of delegate, does it refers to  a correct class at runtime ? The way you demonstrate will not help to find why wrong class in executing. Use either `NSLog`to print OR put a break point and debug window try: `po delegate` or `print delegate` to see the actual class binds at runtime.

Comment: yes.... the delegate is points to another class. Why is that happening? I had actually copy pasted this method from the other class. Is that why?

Comment: Possibly YES, double check what you have set to delegate ? it should refer to correct class. or show the code where you set delegate.

Comment: actually what is happening is, the first time delegate takes the correct class. Its only when `-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method is called, it changes to the other class.

Comment: i have updated the question with code.

Comment: Do you set the `delegate` of UITextField by code or by Interface Builder ? If by code then show us the code where you are setting its delegate.

Comment: i am setting it programmatically in `CellforRowAtIndexPath` method. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code,

`lbl1.delegate=self;`

If delegate should represent class other than ITSELF, THAN its value is wrong. It should be set to some other delegate class:

`lbl1.delegate = _delegateClass;`

Here: `_delegateClass` represents some other class than itself.

for example: (psuedocode)

.h File:

```
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController

@end
```

.m file:

```
@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      // initialize view controller here
      // set _delegate to self
}

@end
```

.h File:

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
{
    // declare textfield here
}
@property id _delegate;
@end
```

.m file:

```
@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2
@synthesize _delegate

...
...   // Here set : textfield.delegate = _delegate; // now it refers to viewController1 and all event of textfield will be handle in ViewController1
...
@end
```

I tried to be descriptive/ in detail as much a I can now.

Happy Coding!!